# Definition of Orthogonal Vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

> Let $z=(z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n)$ and $w=(w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Define the inner product of $z$ and $w$ as
>   $$\langle z,w \rangle=z_1\overline{w_1}+z_2\overline{w_2}+\dots+z_n\overline{w_n},$$
>   where $\overline{w_j}$ is complex conjugate of $w_j$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$.

Since $\langle z,w \rangle \neq \langle w,z \rangle$, how can we say that $z$ and $w$ are orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\langle x,y \rangle = \overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$$
And we call $x$ and $y$ ortogonal if
$$\langle x, y \rangle = 0$$

Comment: Should $\langle y,x \rangle=0$ too? Or $\langle x,y \rangle=0$ if and only if $\langle y,x \rangle=0$?

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN If $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$ then $\langle y, x \rangle = \overline{\langle x,y \rangle} = \overline{0} = 0$. So we have that $x$ is orthogonal to $y$ if and only if $y$ is orthogonal to $x$, which is what we want.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN Orthogonality is symmetric